# How to create a Facebook user access token programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

Is there a possibility to get a Facebook user access token, given that I have the user's credentials?

The background is that I am writing a console application which shall act on the user's behalf, and as it's a console application, of course I can not do the OAuth dance.

Is there a request I can make, such as

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/getUserAccessToken?login=foo&password=bar
```

?

Comment: No, there is no API for that, and users should not give their login credentials to any third party. Actually asking for that info would get your app blocked quite quickly, I suppose.

Comment: So ... what do I do in this case, if I have a console application and want it to work with Facebook on behalf of a user? For obvious reasons, I can not do OAuth and browser integration. Any idea?

Comment: That is the whole point of using an Access Token, so that users wont have to give away their credentials to any third party. I can't think of any other way of doing it. But, I'm curious to know how did you manage their credentials. ;)

Comment: Well, it's just a command-line tool I am writing for myself, hence I trust the app ;-)